# How can i add a button programmatically and when clicked invoke its event handler?

Tags: asp.net, button, drop-down-menu

I want to create a button programmatically and when i click that button i want to invoke its event handler....This is my code.......What am I doing wrong??

```
protected void DashboardDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button objbutton = new Button();
    objbutton.ID = "objbutton";
    objbutton.Text = "Hello";
    form1.Controls.Add(objbutton);
    Page.Controls.Add(form1);
    objbutton.Click += new System.EventHandler(objbutton_Click);


}
protected void objbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

If i click **objbutton** then **DashboardDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged** event gets Fired instead of objbutton_Click

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
protected void DashboardDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button objbutton = new Button();
    objbutton.ID = "objbutton";
    objbutton.Click += new System.EventHandler(objbutton_Click);
    objbutton.Text = "Hello";
    form1.Controls.Add(objbutton);


}
protected void objbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Try to set AutoPostback property of DropDownEdit to true